# Accessing fredhopper on a linux server from Windows Machine

Tags: 2013, smarttarget, fredhopper, linux

My web application is hosted on windows machine and fredhopper is installed on linux. If anybody can help me out to get the list of Triggers types from linux machine. I am using OData web service to retrieve the Triggers types but it looks it requires Smarttarget deployment web service(SmartTargetDeploymentWebService.war) to get the list of Triggers types. I am getting below error while trying to add the promotions in CMS.

```
2015-10-07 04:07:29,592 DEBUG WebServiceExecutor - Trying to retrieve a result within a timeout of 5000 ms.
2015-10-07 04:07:29,592 DEBUG LiveAttributes - Getting a list of Attributes
2015-10-07 04:07:29,655 DEBUG WebServiceExecutor - Contacting URL: http://ServerIPAdress:8180/fredhopper/config/attributes/catalog01/en_US/list
2015-10-07 04:07:29,670 ERROR WebServiceExecutor - Failed to load the list of Attributes. Response status code: 404
2015-10-07 04:07:29,670 DEBUG WebServiceExecutor - Fredhopper Web service call for retrieved result in: 78 ms.
2015-10-07 04:07:29,670 ERROR AttributeResolver - Unable to get a list of Attributes.
com.tridion.smarttarget.SmartTargetException: Unable to get a list of Attributes. Please refer to the SmartTarget log files for more information.
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.attributes.LiveAttributes.getLiveAttributes(LiveAttributes.java:39) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.attributes.LiveAttributes.getLiveAttributes(LiveAttributes.java:16) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.webservices.attributes.AttributeResolver.getAttributes(AttributeResolver.java:74) ~[smarttarget_api_webservice.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.smarttarget.webservices.attributes.AttributeResolver.resolveCollection(AttributeResolver.java:36) ~[smarttarget_api_webservice.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.resolver.ResolverBase.resolve(ResolverBase.java:74) [cd_odata.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataFeedRenderer.renderODataFeed(ODataFeedRenderer.java:45) [cd_odata.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.handleODataEntity(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:141) [cd_odata.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.handleResourceRequest(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:117) [cd_odata.jar:na]
2015-10-07 04:07:29,670 DEBUG AmbientRuntime - Ambient Data context initialization.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart target deployment webservice is only used to push the Smart target enabled components from Tridion to Fredhopper and it is not relevant to retrieve the promotions from Frdhopper. Please refer following [doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-8D2EE604-2C43-4793-A333-B5146F00BB72) for more details.

From your shared log, i noticed an issue with server IP address and hence it throws 404 error. Please provide the correct Frehopper query server IP address in your smarttarget_conf.xml of your OData webservice.

"http://**ServerIPAdress**:8180/fredhopper/config/attributes/catalog01/en_US/list"

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AARX The ServerIPAddress is correct in the smarttarget_conf.xml. I just used the word "ServerIPAddress" for notation only. I don't get the use of "http://ServerIPAdress:8180/fredhopper/config/attributes/catalog01/en_US/list" this url. What is this meant for. Because on my Fredhopper server this directory doesn't exist. My Fredhopper is installed on Linux environment.

Comment: @Sumit, url "http://ServerIPAdress:8180/fredhopper/config/attributes/catalog01/en_US/list" is used to get list of Fredhopper attribues. Can you try hitting this url on your CM server where oData webservice installed. Check on chrome console/fiddler to see why 404 error is occuring. Also check whether your Fredhopper instance is up and running? You can check with following url for indexer preview http://ServerIPAddress:8180/preview/

Comment: @AARX Thanks for the reply. For **en_US** locale its not working but for **en_GB** it is working. In Fredhopper Business Manager, **en_GB** is the only locale which is coming up. Could you please guide on this. Fredhopper instance is up and running fine.

Comment: @Sumit, default locale installed out of the box Fredhopper installation is en_US. Not sure, why its not working for you. I would suggest opening a support ticket to get more help to fix that. Meanwhile, you can give a try with providing en_GB as default locale in your smarttarget_conf.xml and restart the oData webservice and try targeting tab.

Comment: **@AARX** I am not sure how the default locale is set to **en_GB** in Fredhopper business manager. But you are right, after changing in smarttarget_conf.xml to **en_GB** its working fine now and no error is occurring. Will create a ticket to setup the default locale correct.

Comment: @Sumit, glad to hear that changing the locale temporarily resolved the issue. If you think, my suggestions helped you in right direction, mark it as "Answered".